# How do I create a pyUpdater Keypack

Tags: python, pyupdater

I'm trying to create a pyUpdater keypack while following along with the pyUpdater Demo (http://pyupdater-wx-demo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#running-from-source) 
but I receive this error.

Pip Command

```
pyupdater keys -c
```

Result

```
272 INFO: PyUpdater 2.5.3
[INFO] PyUpdater 2.5.3
275 ERROR: You can not create off-line keys on your dev machine
[ERROR] You can not create off-line keys on your dev machine
```

Expected

```
$ pyupdater keys -c
Are you sure you want to continue?
[N/y]?y
Please enter app name - No Default Available
--> PyUpdaterWxDemo
You entered PyUpdaterWxDemo, is this correct?
[N/y]?y
[INFO] Keypack placed in cwd
```

I have tried creating the keys with my computer offline but that didn't seem to have any effect. I have searched on stack overflow and didn't see this question. Nor did I find anything on google. Does anyone know how to create a keypack?

Documentation
http://www.pyupdater.org/usage-cli/

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is old, but I went through the same problem right now and the answer is to run the command in a directory other than the root of your application. It worked to me.

Comment: Solved my problem! Thanks! This answer should be flagged as the best.

Comment: Worked for me! I had to source the .venv BEFORE running the program (otherwise "pyupdater" doesn't exist), which was easy enough to do by sourcing the environment then cd to a different directory.